# Having trouble updating Nuxt layout dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

EDIT: Would it just be a better design pattern to create a layout for an authenticated page and redirect after login not using a conditional on the homepage and instead a middleware that redirects unauthenticated users to the homepage?

I have transitioned the app to SSR and am working out the authentication details, any resources or design advice are welcome!

---

I searched people having the same problem and tried various alternatives with no success so I was wondering if anyone has any clues to where I might be going wrong here. Thanks in advance!

The following code should explain the problem I'm having.I'm using Nuxt SPA and having trouble updating layout according the store.

The console.log('auth or not') returns true, and in my template Authenticated = {{isAuth}} also returns true.

The thing is when I save the code in vscode the layout updates accordinly but then when I refresh it returns to 'default' even thought the session is saved and the store getter isAuth returns true.

Offtopic questions (Feel free to desconsider)

I am a self taught developer so if you see any anti-patterns(there will probably be many) I am open to advice.

Would you recommend Nuxt for an SPA project over plain vue, vuex, vue-router or in your opinion should I just transition to SSR since I am at the beggining of the project.

This is a volunteer project so I'm just trying to improve my skills and help a friend out while I'm at it. Any learning resources will be greatly appreciated!

```js
 import { fireDb } from '~/plugins/firebaseconfig.js'
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          writeSuccessful: false,
          userLoggedIn: false,
        }
      },
      beforeCreate() {
          console.log('before create')
          let _this = this;
          console.log(sessionStorage);
          Object.keys(sessionStorage).forEach((e, i) => {
          //getting user info from session storage
          if(JSON.parse(sessionStorage[e]).uid) {
            let user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage[e]);

            let userInfo = {
              userEmail: user.userEmail,
              userThumbnail: user.photoURL,
              userName: user.displayName
            };
            _this.$store.commit('userLogin', userInfo)
            console.log('auth or not')
            console.log(this.$store.getters.isAuth);

          }
        })

      },
      computed:
        mapGetters({
          anuncios: 'anuncios/get',
          isAuth: 'isAuth'
        }),
      layout({store}) { return store.getters.isAuth ? 'authenticated' : 'default' },
```

Sorry for the long post and thanks again to anyone who took the time to read it!

Comment: I think beginning with Nuxt is a good idea because Nuxt is basically (not only) an opiniated way to use Vue.js. Nuxt will show you the good patterns to use with Vue.

Comment: @PierreSaid That's a good point, I'm going to try recreating this project in SSR and see if I can get it working for now. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Dynamic layout changing in Nuxt doesn't work. But you can read the name of the layout from store. And if the layout changed you have to reload the page. See my example project: https://github.com/urbansky/switch-layout

Answer (score 0):

After switching to SSR mode I was able to better debug, I figured that the beforeCreate hook is called after the layout is mounted after switching to SSR which I should have realized after seeing this image on the nuxt documentation. So I realized the isAuth state getter was being checked before the authentication happening in the beforeCreate where I was supposed to be checking the sessionStorage.

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views

Also found this to help out authentication using middleware.

https://auth.nuxtjs.org/

I solved my problem but am still insecure about my design patterns so still open to criticism and please correct me if there is anything wrong with my answer!

---

EDIT

I found an example which really helped me out, if anyone else is struggling with authentication with firebase and nuxt check out the following example by davidroyer.

https://github.com/davidroyer/nuxt-ssr-firebase-auth.v2